# Change TextBlock Background based on the value of Text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I want to change the Background property of a TextBlock if the Text is **00:00**.Is there a simple, XAML solution? I've tried creating a DataTrigger but it's not changing the colour

```
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="textBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="00:00">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="3" Style="{DynamicResource textBlock}"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about a normal `Trigger`?:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="textBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="00:00">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your binding in your datatrigger should be

```
Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Text}"
```

Comment: While your `Binding` syntax *is* correct, there is no point in using a `DataTrigger` with its `Binding` that requires extra resources if it is possible to do the same thing using the lighter-weight `Trigger` instead.